# What's the difference between GCDC, GraphicsContext and DC

Tags: python, wxpython

From the documentation (Phoenix) I understood that **GCDC** is device context layer on top of **GraphicsContext**, which in turn is a layer on top of **DC** (PaintDC, ClientDC, WindowDC, ScreenDC, MemoryDC or PrinterDC).

What is the primary difference between these? I've noticed Antialiasing is not available in PaintDC, but that can't be the only difference, can it?

Here's something from the docs:

> wxWidgets offers an alternative drawing API based on the modern drawing backends GDI+, CoreGraphics and Cairo. See GraphicsContext, GraphicsRenderer and related classes. There is also a GCDC linking the APIs by offering the DC API on top of a GraphicsContext.

Does this mean that GraphicsContext lacks some features provided by DC, and GCDC fills the gap?